# Make Bash Export permanent

Tags: python, bash, vim

I was having an issue where my pynopath was not the same place as where my pip installs were.

My coworker solved this by setting:

```
 export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But he said that I need to make this permanent so that it does not exist only in this terminal instance.

How can I do this?

I tried vim ~/.bashrc however it created a new file rather than allowing me to edit one.

Comment: if you don't have a .bashrc, then it's OK to create a new one and add that line ... bash should detect that it was created the next time you start up a terminal...

Comment: that line specifically? I don't need to modify it? So that solution is correct?

Comment: I'm wondering how did you install your packages that you need to mess with your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yep, putting that exact line into it should work, but @BurhanKhalid has a valid point.  That path _should_ already be on your PYTHONPATH...

Comment: Do you have two versions of Python installed?

Comment: No, I'm running 2.7 however I googled it and it appears pip installs to a linux based path ex /usr/lib/.../python/ but my computer expects it at a osx Library/.... path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Just create it if it doesnt exist. I dont know any distrib which doesnt recognize it